# extract multiple lines of a file unix

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

I have a file A with 400,000 lines. I have another file B that has a bunch of line numbers.

```
File B:  
-------
98  
101
25012
10098
23489
```

I have to extract those line numbers specified in file B from file A. That is I want to extract lines 98,101,25012,10098,23489 from file A. How to extract these lines in the following cases.

1. File B is a explicit file.
2. File B is arriving out of a pipe. For eg., grep -n pattern somefile.txt is giving me the file B.

I wanted to use see -n 'x'p fileA. However, I don't know how to give the 'x' from a file. Also, I don't to how to pipe the value of 'x' from a command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` can print the line numbers you want:

```
$ printf $'foo\nbar\nbaz\n' | sed -ne '2p'
bar
```

If you want multiple lines:

```
$ printf $'foo\nbar\nbaz\n' | sed -ne '2p;3p'
bar
baz
```

To transform a set of lines to a `sed` command like this, use `sed` for beautiful `sed`ception:

```
$ printf $'98\n101' | sed -e 's/$/;/'
98;
101;
```

Putting it all together:

```
sed -ne "$(sed -e 's/$/p;/' B)" A
```

Testing:

```
$ cat A
1
22
333
4444
$ cat B
1
3
$ sed -ne "$(sed -e 's/$/p;/' B)" A
1
333
```

QED.

Comment: you meant `s/$/p;/` right? also would this work if in fileB there are 30k lines?

Comment: When I execute just this $(sed -e 's/$/p;/' B), it display every linenumber; in a new line. That is 98;\n101;\n. Hence when I run the command in total, sed -e $(sed -e 's/$/;/' B) A, I get an error "sed: 31494p;: No such file or directory". I think the first sed with the fileB should also remove the newline.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test the last statement. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

awk fits this task better:

fileA in file case:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next}a[FNR]' fileB fileA
```

fileA content from pipe:

```
cat fileA|awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]=1;next}a[FNR]' fileB -
```

oh, you want FileB in file or from pipe, then same awk cmd:

```
awk '...' fileB fileA
```

and

```
cat fileB|awk '...' - fileA
```