# Print many specific rows from a text file using an index file

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a large text file with over 100 million rows, called `reads.fastq`. Further I have another file called `takeThese.txt` that contains row numbers from the file `reads.fastq` that should be printed (one per row).

Currently I use

`awk 'FNR == NR { h[$1]; next } (FNR in h)' takeThese.txt reads.fastq > subsample.fastq`

Apparently that takes really long. Is there any way to extract rows from a text file using row numbers stored in another file? Would it speed things up, if the `takeThese.txt` file would be sorted?

EDIT:

A few example rows of the files I have:

`reads.fastq`:

```
@HWI-1KL157:36:C2468ACXX
TGTTCAGTTTCTTCGTTCTTTTTTTGGAC
+
@@@DDDDDFF>FFGGC@F?HDHIHIFIGG
@HWI-1KL157:36:C2468ACXX
CGAGGCGGTGACGGAGAGGGGGGAGACGC
+
BCCFFFFFHHHHHIGHHIHIJJDDBBDDD
@HWI-1KL157:36:C2468ACXX
TCATATTTTCTGATTTCTCCGTCACTCAA
```

`takeThese.txt` :

```
5
6
7
8
```

So that the output would look like this:

```
@HWI-1KL157:36:C2468ACXX
CGAGGCGGTGACGGAGAGGGGGGAGACGC
+
BCCFFFFFHHHHHIGHHIHIJJDDBBDDD
```

EDIT: Comparison of the suggested scripts:

```
$ time perl AndreasWederbrand.pl takeThese.txt reads.fastq  > /dev/null

real    0m1.928s
user    0m0.819s
sys     0m1.100s

$ time ./karakfa  takeThese_numbered.txt reads_numbered.fastq  > /dev/null

real    0m8.334s
user    0m9.973s
sys     0m0.226s

$ time ./EdMorton takeThese.txt reads.fastq  > /dev/null

real    0m0.695s
user    0m0.553s
sys     0m0.130s

$ time ./ABrothers  takeThese.txt reads.fastq  > /dev/null

real    0m1.870s
user    0m1.676s
sys     0m0.186s

$ time ./GlenJackman takeThese.txt reads.fastq  > /dev/null

real    0m1.414s
user    0m1.277s
sys     0m0.147s

$ time ./DanielFischer takeThese.txt reads.fastq  > /dev/null

real    0m1.893s
user    0m1.744s
sys     0m0.138s
```

Thanks for all suggestions and efforts!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [extract multiple lines of a file unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295530/extract-multiple-lines-of-a-file-unix)

Comment: The problem is, the solutions provided in that answer are also rather slow. If there isn't anything faster than that, then this question is certainly a duplicate, sorry - I haven't even found that thread.

Comment: That script seems to output the opposite, ie. the rows not listed in file `takeThese.txt`. For 100M rows (just row numbers as data) in `reads.fastq` and 1M evenly distributed sorted row numbers in the `takeThat.txt` the execution time on my mini laptop was 52 seconds (`>/dev/null`). I think it's worth mentioning that @glennjackman's solution only took 18 seconds.

Comment: I produced my test files with: `awk 'BEGIN {for(i=1;i<=100000000;i++) print i}' > reads.fastq` and `awk 'BEGIN {for(i=1;i<=1000000;i++) print i*100}' > takeThat.txt`, btw, so it's 1000000 evenly distributed hits.

Comment: Thanks to everybody who suggested a method! I compared the corresponding timings for a smaller subset. The results I added to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The script in your question will be extremely fast since all it does is a hash lookup of the current line number in the array `h`. This will be faster still though unless you want to print the last line number from reads.fastq since it exits after the last desired line number is printed instead of continuing reading the rest of reads.fastq:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{h[$1]; c++; next} FNR in h{print; if (!--c) exit}' takeThese.txt reads.fastq
```

You could throw in a `delete h[FNR];` after the `print;` to reduce the array size and so MAYBE speed up the lookup time but idk if that will really improve performance any since the array access is a hash lookup and so will be extremely fast so adding a `delete` may end up slowing the script down overall.

Actually, this will be faster still since it avoids testing NR==FNR for every line in both files:

```
awk -v nums='takeThese.txt' '
    BEGIN{ while ((getline i < nums) > 0) {h[i]; c++} }
    NR in h{print; if (!--c) exit}
' reads.fastq
```

Whether that is faster or the script @glennjackman posted is faster depends on how many lines are in takeThese.txt and how close to the end of the reads.fastq they occur. Since Glenns reads the whole of reads.fastq no matter what the contents of takeThese.txt it'll execute in about constant time while mine will be significantly faster the further from the end of reads.fastq the last line number in takeThese.txt occurs. e.g.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {for(i=1;i<=100000000;i++) print i}' > reads.fastq
```

.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {for(i=1;i<=1000000;i++) print i*100}' > takeThese.txt

$ time awk -v nums=takeThese.txt '
    function next_index() {
        ("sort -n " nums) | getline i
        return i
    }
    BEGIN { linenum = next_index() }
    NR == linenum { print; linenum = next_index() }
' reads.fastq > /dev/null
real    0m28.720s
user    0m27.876s
sys     0m0.450s

$ time awk -v nums=takeThese.txt '
    BEGIN{ while ((getline i < nums) > 0) {h[i]; c++} }
    NR in h{print; if (!--c) exit}
' reads.fastq > /dev/null
real    0m50.060s
user    0m47.564s
sys     0m0.405s
```

.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {for(i=1;i<=100;i++) print i*100}' > takeThat.txt

$ time awk -v nums=takeThat.txt '
    function next_index() {
        ("sort -n " nums) | getline i
        return i
    }
    BEGIN { linenum = next_index() }
    NR == linenum { print; linenum = next_index() }
' reads.fastq > /dev/null
real    0m26.738s
user    0m23.556s
sys     0m0.310s

$ time awk -v nums=takeThat.txt '
    BEGIN{ while ((getline i < nums) > 0) {h[i]; c++} }
    NR in h{print; if (!--c) exit}
' reads.fastq > /dev/null
real    0m0.094s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.000s
```

but you can have the best of both worlds with:

```
$ time awk -v nums=takeThese.txt '
    function next_index() {
        if ( ( ("sort -n " nums) | getline i) > 0 ) {
            return i
        }
        else {
            exit
        }
    }
    BEGIN { linenum = next_index() }
    NR == linenum { print; linenum = next_index() }
' reads.fastq > /dev/null
real    0m28.057s
user    0m26.675s
sys     0m0.498s


$ time awk -v nums=takeThat.txt '
    function next_index() {
        if ( ( ("sort -n " nums) | getline i) > 0 ) {
            return i
        }
        else {
            exit
        }
    }
    BEGIN { linenum = next_index() }
    NR == linenum { print; linenum = next_index() }
' reads.fastq > /dev/null
real    0m0.094s
user    0m0.030s
sys     0m0.062s
```

which if we assume takeThese.txt is already sorted can be reduced to just:

```
$ time awk -v nums=takeThese.txt '
    BEGIN { getline linenum < nums }
    NR == linenum { print; if ((getline linenum < nums) < 1) exit }
' reads.fastq > /dev/null
real    0m27.362s
user    0m25.599s
sys     0m0.280s

$ time awk -v nums=takeThat.txt '
    BEGIN { getline linenum < nums }
    NR == linenum { print; if ((getline linenum < nums) < 1) exit }
' reads.fastq > /dev/null
real    0m0.047s
user    0m0.030s
sys     0m0.016s
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot be sure, if I need the last line number of not. But of course I could test that one then still separately.

Comment: You don't need to be sure or test anything extra, just use it. It won't be noticeably slower when you do need to print the last line number but it will be noticeably faster when you DON'T need to print it. Your script today reads every line of reads.fastq even if takeThese.txt only has line numbers 1 to 10 in it so thats millions of lines read unnecessarily in that case. My script would exit after reading line 10.

Comment: Wow, that is really an elaborate answer, thanks a lot! I sorted the `takeThese.txt` file now, so I can pick your last script. It's currently running, but it takes a while to evaluate the timings on the real data at hand. Also thanks to all other answers here on the page, I'll try to compare them for the real data using the `time`.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that your solution for the sorted lines brings the best improvement to the existing function I used so far!

Answer (score 2):

I *think* that solution in the question stores all lines from takeThese.txt into array, h[], and then for each line in reads.fastq does a linear search in h[] for that line number.

There are several simple improvements to that in different languages. I would try perl if you're not comfortable with java.

Basically you should make sure takeThese.txt is sorted, then just go through reads.fastq one line at at time, scanning for a line number that matches the next line number from takeThese.txt, then pop that and continue.

Since rows are of different length you have no choice but to scan for newline character (basic `for each line`-construct in most languages).

Example in perl, quick and dirty but works

```
open(F1,"reads.fastq");
open(F2,"takeThese.txt");
$f1_pos = 1;
foreach $index (<F2>) {
   while ($f1_pos <= $index) {
      $out = <F1>; $f1_pos++;
   } 
   print $out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, knowing that sorting would speed up things helps. So I'll give it a try.

Comment: So it does exactly what I said, except it's a hash instead of an array. This makes the lookup faster but it still have to hold the entire lookup file in memory and do searches for each line number from reads.fastq in that hash, instead of *knowing* what line number to look for.

Comment: I'm just saying that instead of searching through the hash (which might be very fast) it's better to just keep the current line number being looked for in a variable, not even doing the hash search.

Answer (score 2):

The issue I see with your awk is you are loading all the line numbers you want to extract into an array, and then, for every single line, you need to access that array.

I'm sure that the `in` keyword has to do something along the lines of looping over each element of the array and comparing the value at that index to the `FNR` value...

So if you have 1,000,000 lines you want to extract, for every single line of `reads.fastq` you need to loop over the `1,000,000` lines you want to extract!  100,000,000(reads.fastq lines) X 1,000,000(lookup array length) =`1e+14`.  That's a lot of lookups.

Again awks `in` keyword could do all sorts of fancy tricks and efficient things but in the end you should see why this isn't working out.

One approach is to use a variable that contains the current line we want, an index variable to track where we are in the lookup array, and a max variable to see if we can stop processing the file!  This way we only perform `N` array lookups, one for each line we want, and the rest of the time we are doing comparisons of FNR to a variable, which should be faster.  In addition we stop executing after we print the last line we want.

Obviously this requires that we have a sorted list of lines we want to extract.

`readthese` is your `"takeThese.txt"`.  `list.txt` is a file where the lines are numbered 1 - 1,000,000`

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=1; max=1;} FNR==NR{ if($1 != ""){h[max]=$1;  max++; next}} { if(!l){l=h[i]; i++; } if( FNR == l ){ print $0; l=h[i]; i++; if(i == max){  exit; } } }'
```

In a more readable format

```
 awk '
    BEGIN{i=1; max=1;}

    FNR==NR{ 
        if($1 != ""){
            h[max]=$1;  max++; next
        }
    } 
    { 
        if(!l){
            l=h[i]; i++;
        }

        if( FNR == l ){ 
            print $0;
            l=h[i];
            i++;
            if(i == max){
              exit;
            }
        } 
    }' readthese list.txt
```

`i` is our current place in the `h` array which is where we store the lines we want to extract. `max` is basically the length of the `h` array, when `i == h` we know we can stop.  `l` is the value of the next line we want to extract.

EDIT: You can replace `readthese` with `<(sort -n readthese)` if you need to sort your line file.

Comment: I tried to compare your script to the other ones posted here, but it only gives the rows between 1 and 9, if the index is larger, it doesn't print them.

Comment: Whops!  Looks like i managed to mangle both commands when moving them to stack overflow, fixing them now... Also it's vital that `takeThese.txt` is sorted and doesn't contain empty lines or anything weird.

Comment: Thanks! I really should learn more about `awk` to be able to fix those issues by myself.

Answer (score 2):

I would try one of these

1. may result in false positives:

   ```
   cat -n reads.fastq | grep -Fwf takeThese.txt | cut -d$'\t' -f20
   ```
2. requires one of {bash,ksh,zsh}:

   ```
   sed -n -f <(sed 's/$/p/' takeThese.txt) reads.fastq
   ```
3. this is similar to Andreas Wederbrand's perl answer, implemented in awk

   ```
   awk -v nums=takeThese.txt '
       function next_index() {
           ("sort -n " nums) | getline i
           return i
       }
       BEGIN { linenum = next_index() }
       NR == linenum { print; linenum = next_index() }
   ' reads.fastq
   ```

But, if you're dealing with a lot of data, text processing tools will take time. Your other option is to import the data into a proper database and use SQL to extract it: database engines are built for this kind of stuff.

Comment: I created test files with 100M rows and another with 1M row numbers and tried a few (3 actually) approaches to solving this with awk. This awk solution was faster than any of mine. ++

Answer (score 2):

As I have the flu and am bored I tested some approaches to try to quicken the original solution. The test files:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {for(i=1;i<=100000000;i++) print i}' > reads.fastq
```

and

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {for(i=1;i<=1000000;i++) print i*100}' > takeThat.txt
```

The first file is just numbers from 1 to 100000000. It does not represent the real data but I was curious about the execution times between awk solutions so I assumed that the real data would only multiply the result times with a constant (before the memory starts to run out).

The second file represents one percent evenly distributed hit ratio to the first file:

```
100
200
300
...
```

First, the OP's original script:

```
$ time awk 'FNR==NR {h[$1]; next} (FNR in h)' takeThese.txt reads.fastq > /dev/null

real    0m52.901s
user    0m52.596s
sys     0m0.284s
```

My solution:

```
BEGIN {
    j=1
    while((getline a[++i] < "takeThese.txt") > 0 );  # row numbers to a
} 
NR<a[j] { next }                                     # skip rows before next match
j++                                                  # print and iterate j
j==i { exit }                                        # exit after last hit
```

Timed run:

```
$ time awk -f program.awk reads.fastq > /dev/null

real    0m25.894s
user    0m25.676s
sys     0m0.208s
```

The row number file `takeThese.txt` is expected to be ordered.

Answer (score 2):

late to the party but this might a fast alternative as well.  It leverages `join`s raw speed, but need to convert matching fields to be in lexicographical order.

```
$ join <(awk '{printf "%09d\n", $1}' pick.list) <(nl -w9 -ba -nrz big.file) | 
  cut -d' ' -f2-
```

preprocess your pick list to add the leading zeros, add line numbers your big file with leading zeros (same width), assumes your pick list is in numerical order, otherwise sort first.

Change the file names for "pick.list" and "big.file" with your own filenames.  Also, if the big file has more than 999,999,999 rows, adjust the widths accordingly ("%09" and "w9").

If you try this please post your timings.  My guess is it will be much faster than `awk` alternatives.

**nl options**

> `w9` number width is 9
>   `ba` add numbers to blank lines as well in text body
>   `nrz` format number with leading zeros, right aligned i.e. `000000001`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. For adding the leading zeros, I'll use `awk -F: '{ printf "%09d %s\n", $1,$2 }' takeThese.txt` and `awk '{printf("%09d %s\n", NR,$0)}' reads.fastq`

Comment: What is the second field in the pick list? `join` will only use the first field by default, which is supposed to be the line number you're searching in the big file.  The other should be fine but `nl` is faster.

Comment: There is no second field in the pick list. As I wrote earlier, my shell scripting is copy+paste from other questions and I try out what works. So I could actually delete the `$2`, you are right.

Comment: In the test run the `join` performed surprisingly slow compared to the `awk` solution when I run it on a smaller test sample with 2.5 mio entries. Over night I'll keep it then running for the full data.

Comment: I tried this solution on the same laptop as mine and: `real 2m27.746s,
user 2m26.780s, sys 0m0.848s`.

Comment: That is what I was thought, but even when I exclude the setup steps from the timing, the `join` is still slower than `awk`. But I have to admit, that I haven't tried it yet on the full data.

Answer (score 0):

Are the lines in `reads.fastq` all of the same length?

If so, a simple algorithm in Java or any other language could take every line number in `takeThese.txt` and find the position where the line starts in `reads.fastq` by multiplying the line number with line length.

If not, then the only way to find the right line is to count newlines, which means reading every character. That could still be faster than awk, and it definitely helps to sort the line numbers.

Comment: No, unfortunately the row lengths differ, and entries come in blocks of four. The problem is, I am not very fluent in awk or sed, so maybe I formulated the problem wrongly. E.g. the R equivalent would be like this: `reads.fastq[takeThese.txt, ]` (assuming the objects would be named as the files are called).